# KL divergence calculation

Tags: distributions, machine-learning, distance-functions, information-retrieval

I am wondering that how one can calculate [KL-divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) on two probability distributions. For example, if we have

```
t1 = 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.05, 0.05
t2 = 0.23, 0, 0.14, 0.17
```

The formula is bit complicated for me :(

Comment: t2 does not add up to one and is thus no valid probability. If you don't fix that, you will get weird results.

Comment: @bayer: I had read these as equally probable values in my answer below.  I now see they might be probabilities: before the question was changed, they did add up to 1. That would make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

Using brute force and the first formula [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence) based on the first formula for the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence), you are starting from two multisets each with 5 values, 3 of which are shared between them.  So the combination of them is the multiset 
$$M={0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4}$$

so using $D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P\|Q) = \sum_i P(i) \log \frac{P(i)}{Q(i)}$

$$JSD(t_1 \parallel t_2)= \frac{1}{2}D_{\mathrm{KL}}(t_1 \parallel M)+\frac{1}{2}D_{\mathrm{KL}}(t_2 \parallel M)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(1\cdot\frac{2}{5} \log\left(\frac{2/5}{2/10}\right) +3\cdot\frac{1}{5} \log\left(\frac{1/5}{2/10}\right)\right)  $$
$$+\frac{1}{2}\left(2\cdot\frac{1}{5} \log\left(\frac{1/5}{1/10}\right) +3\cdot\frac{1}{5} \log\left(\frac{1/5}{2/10}\right)\right)  $$
$$= \dfrac{2}{5}\log(2) \approx 0.277$$

though you may want to check this. Other calculations, such as using Shannon entropy should produce the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Is it the standard formula for JS? and why did you mention 3 are same between two distributions? Is it important? Do I need to calculate this as well when I perform JS? How did you get 2/5? 1/5?

Comment: OP wanted to find $D_{\mathrm{KL}}$, right? Why do you find JSD? Sorry if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Ashok: I asked the question as it was at the time. It has since changed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I really don't understand how you obtained `M`. The wiki page for JSD says `$M=0.5*(P+Q)$`?

Comment: @Legend [The original question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/24059d76-20dc-4e33-8918-5fe37c49e581/view-source) was for $t1 = 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.05, 0.05$ and $t2 = 0.3, 0, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2$ so $M$ was simply the two them combined as a multiset.

Comment: @Henry: Thank you for the clarification. I did not notice that the question was changed. I'd appreciate if you could also clarify how this `M` is related to what has been given on the wiki page i.e. `M=0.5(P+Q)`?

Comment: @Legend: the probability of choosing $0.05$ from $t1$ was $2/5$ and of choosing $0.05$ from $t2$ was $0$, and of choosing $0.05$ from $M$ was $2/10 = \frac12(2/5+0)$